# 1st) Identify Column 2nd) Identify value in column 3) Insert data from that row into array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to gather the horizontal data (left to right) Beginning in cell I10 - I am first trying to code the macro to identify the correct ledger account in column I. Column I is below with I:10 pepresenting the column I want, `Dividend Income`

```
Ledger Account
Prior Shares Outstanding
Current Shares Outstanding
Current Share Activity
Previous Net Assets
Current Net Assets
Net Asset Change
Market Value
Trading Gain Loss
Dividend Income
```

I have the below code, I am trying to insert the the data in the cells to the RIGHT of I10 (I:10 to Z:10) into an array.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    SearchString = "Ledger Account"

    '~~> Change this as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> 5 Denotes the 5th column i.e Column "E"
            '~~> Amend as applicable
            '~~> Store the values From say Col B to E in the array
            MyAr = Application.Transpose( _
                                         .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row, 2), _
                                                .Cells(aCell.Row, 5) _
                                                ).Value _
                                        )

            '~~> Check what is in the array
            For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                Debug.Print MyAr(i, 1)
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you searching column one or column I? Your code has column one.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question confusing.

Example 1: what is `I:10 to Z:10`?  Do you mean `I10 to Z10` or `I10:Z10`?  The colon goes between two single cell addresses to define a range.

Example 2: the text implies the list of account names are in column I (=9) but your code searches column 1 (=A).

In this answer I give you information that I hope will point you in the correct direction.

---

Consider: `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`.

The user can have several workbooks open.  Let us call then A, B, C and D.  The user can have A active but call a macro in D.  When this situation is possible, you can use `ActiveWorkbook` to refer to the active workbook and `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the workbook containing the macro.  If you think there is a possibility that the user will call the macro from another workbook, you are correct to specifically identify that you want a worksheet from the workbook containing the macro.  Otherwise `Set ws = Sheets(1)` would have given you a worksheet within the active workbook.

Avoid `Sheets(1)` or `Sheets(2)`.  Here the 1 and 2 refer to the sequence within the tab row which the user can change easily either deliberately or accidentally.  Create a new workbook and copy this code to a module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim InxWsht As Long

  For InxWsht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Debug.Print Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
  Next

End Sub
```

If you have an English version of Excel with the default number of sheets, this macro will output the following to the Immediate Window:

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
```

Now move Sheet2 so it is after Sheet3 and rerun the macro.  The output is now:

```
Sheet1
Sheet3
Sheet2
```

Always identify worksheets by name; for example: Worksheets("Ledgers") so the user cannot accidentally break your macro.

---

Consider `Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find . . .`

As I said this searches column 1 although your text says column I.  This might just be a typographical error but it is better to avoid using literals for columns in the body of your code.  Columns move as new columns are added or the users want a new sequence.  Searching through code trying to identify which numbers refer to a column so you can update them can be a nightmare which is easily avoided.

```
Const ColName As Long = 9
```

or

```
Const ColName As String = "I"
```

allows you to write

```
Set aCell = .Columns(ColName).Find . . .
```

Now if the column containing the ledger names moves, one change at the top updates the code.  There is also the advantage that “ColName” means something to a future maintenance programmer (which might be you).  If you had ever tried to update a macro in which the author refers to 20 different columns by number, you would understand why I like names.

---

I loaded your list of names to column “A” of worksheet “Ledgers”.  Below is a modified version of your macro.  Study my changes and attempt to understand why I made them.  Come back with questions as necessary but the more you can work out for yourself, the faster you will develop.

```
Sub Sample()

    Const ColName As Long = 1
    Const ColFirstWanted As Long = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ColCrnt As Long   ' Avoid names like i; they can get very confusing.
    Dim ColLast As Long

    SearchString = "Dividend Income"

    '~~> Change this as applicable
    Set ws = Worksheets("Ledgers")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(ColName).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Find last used column in row
            ColLast = .Cells(aCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            '~~> Amend as applicable
            '~~> Store the values From say Col B to E in the array
            '## Note: Transpose is slow when called from VBA.
            MyAr = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row, ColFirstWanted), .Cells(aCell.Row, ColLast)).Value

            '~~> Check what is in the array
            ' ## Note: Although the worksheet row is not 1 and the first column is not 1,
            ' ##       the lower bounds are both 1. This can be confusing. I suggest
            ' ##       loading the entire row so the worksheet column numbers match the array
            ' ##       column numbers.  A few extra columns in the array is a small price to pay
            ' ##       reduced confusion.
            For ColCrnt = LBound(MyAr, 2) To UBound(MyAr, 2)
                Debug.Print ColCrnt & " " & MyAr(1, ColCrnt)
            Next ColCrnt
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```